# Change CSS file by jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, resize, window

I'm trying to change the CSS file on the page with jQuery using [.resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/).

I've spent a couple of hours trying to figure it out, and now I need help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        if(w < '640px')
        {
            $('#pcss').attr('href', 'css/pagestyle640.css');
        }
        else if(w > '640px')
        {
            $('#pcss').attr('href', 'css/pagestyle.css');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It is often helpful to post both html and javascript in a resource such as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: next time i will, i was a bit rushed when i posted this and seeing how helpful this site is ill be back to post more q's maybe answer a few and definitely work on making my q's a lot more presentable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/width/). The .width method returns a number. I believe you are running into issues comparing a number against a string here:

```
if(w < '640px')
```

You would be better off:

```
if(w < 640)
```

Comment: yup completely works now, so stupid how the smallest problem throws me back and forth for hours.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use are [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries). You can do all this without a line of javascript.

You can add stylesheets like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 640px)" />
```

This will only get applied if the screen is narrower than 640px.

As for legacy browser support, you can use this polyfill: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond
Also there is a really nice and simple demo page to it.

Comment: This seems like the most practical option, but I'd like to learn how to use resize() as there are other functions I want to implement. Thank you for this, it'll keep things a lot simpler

Comment: I'm not trying to be greedy but since you are new here: upvoting an answer if it is helpful to you is very welcome, as it is a decent motivation for people to write other answers.

Comment: i cant upvote until i hit a rep of 15, i tried once i hit 15 ill come back and upvote.

Comment: @SoonDead - If you like Daphatti's question or comments, you could upvote those and Daphatti might hit a rep of 15 sooner.